# Feign request interceptor is sending an incorrect header's value (is concatenating the name + value inside the value)

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I'm trying to add 2 headers to a request made with feign using an interceptor, using spring-boot 2.5.9, but I'm receiving this error:

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [POST] to [http://xxxxx/api/files/files] [FilesClient#upload(String,MultipartFile,String)]
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Feign client:**

```
@FeignClient(name = "files", url = "${feign.clients.files.url}")
public interface FilesClient {
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    FileUploadResponse upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
                              @RequestHeader String path);
}
```

**FeignRequestInterceptor:**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FeignRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor{

  @Override
  public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
    Map<String, Collection<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(Constants.AUTH_HEADER, Collections.singleton(Access.token()));
    headers.put(Constants.X_TENANT_ID, Collections.singleton(Access.getCurrentTenant()));
    requestTemplate.headers(headers);
    log.error("Feign interceptor");
  }
}
```

In the debug I'm reviewing the header's value and I realize that each value has the header's name:

[image]

This is inside Feign HeaderTemplate.java:

[image]

This is causing the auth token value to be sent to the service with an incorrect value.

How to prevent feign from concatenating header name to value?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me and I think it solves your problem

```
  @Component
  public class FeignRequestInterceptor implements 
  RequestInterceptor 
{

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        final RequestAttributes requestAttributes = 
        RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes != null) {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = 
        ((ServletRequestAttributes) 
          requestAttributes).getRequest();
        template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, 
        httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
    }
}
```